# Debugging ASP.NET 5 on local IIS

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET 5 project that I want to host on a local IIS. In the old Visual Studio / ASP.NET I was able to host the development-project on a local IIS (instead of IIS Experss). This is something i'd like to do with my new ASP.NET 5 project too.

I am able to deploy it by using the HttpPlatformHandler-module and app.UseIISPlatformHandler(). Nevertheless I am not able to set the local IIS to my development project and debug it in Visual Studio.

There is no web.cmd-file in my debugging-project like it is in the deployed one.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this? Am i overlooking something?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the term ASP.NET 5. It's not called like this anymore. The name is ASP.NET Core.